# Marklogic Ops Director email alert

Tags: marklogic

We have a question regarding the Ops Director. Is it possible to send a mail of all critical alerts which we are getting on “Monitor view” to a particular mail id from OpsDirector?

I can receive the test email but not receive any alert email even I was select Threshold is "all"

Marklogic Version 10.0-2

Ops Director 2.0.1-1

Comment: So it sounds like  you have defined your resource groups,  and defined the smtp relay. Are you using authenticated or unauthenticated smpt? Have you checked the server ErrorLog, or the application ErrorLog for any messages?

Comment: @MichaelGardner Yes, I defined my resource group and SMTP relay, I'm using authenticated SMTP, I checked the error logs I have the messages.

Comment: I suggest adding the messages to the question.  Did execute the script to change the 'From' email address?  Some mail systems are picky about any differences between the account sending the message and the From address.

Comment: I tried with two different "From" address but no luck, I didn't receive any email from ops director. and logs also having a message @MichaelGardner

Comment: I would recommend opening a ticket with [MarkLogic Support](https://help.marklogic.com)